# How can I create an hyperlink over an image with an irregular shape?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have the world map on a web page. Suppose the user clicks on a country. I would like to attach a specific event to the user click based on the country clicked (example: it opens the wikipedia page of the country).

How can I proceed to detect the country and/or use an irregular shape rather than the area of a circle or rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below links,

[Irregular anchors and shapes using JS in HTML/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693159/irregular-anchors-and-shapes-using-js-in-html-html5)

[Creating irregular shaped HTML links with image maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105055/creating-irregular-shaped-html-links-with-image-maps)

[Can I use CSS hover on this complex irregular shaped link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846267/can-i-use-css-hover-on-this-complex-irregular-shaped-link)

Please do search the site before posting a question. You might find some relevant answers already present in the site.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a javascript library like D3.js
[Sample 1](http://code.minnpost.com/simple-map-d3/)

[Sample 2](http://codepen.io/maggiben/pen/snljd)

The syntax use chaining method and is really easy to ready what a line of code does:

```
 d3.selectAll(".country").style("stroke-width", 1.5 / s);
```

There are a lot of tutorial, and you want to make the country clickable and attach an event right ? well this library is awesome for that.

[Starting guide](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3)